# Connect NGINX proxy to Envoy for gRPC-Web

Tags: nginx, grpc, reverse-proxy, envoyproxy, grpc-web

I am currently developing a webapp with a gRPC backend. For this I am using gRPC-Web and the Envoy proxy between the webapp and the backend service. It is all going fine but now I wanted to deploy it to a digitalocean server and was setting up NGINX as a reverse proxy and to serve my `index.html` file. The following is basically my architecture with the ports of the individual services. The Envoy proxy and the gRPC backend are running in Docker containers:
[image: System Design]

My `nginx.conf` now looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/;

    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name myDomain.com

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri /index.html?$args;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
    }
}
```

Now I am getting the error

```
grpc-message: "unknown service api/proto.Service"
grpc-status: "12"
```

even if the method *is* implemented and it is running great locally.
Any help is highly appreciated :)

EDIT:
After some debugging, I am thinking that returning the answer from the service through Envoy and Nginx is the issue.
For example, when I send the request while the Envoy proxy is running *BUT* the backend service is not running, I am getting the correct error `503 (Service Unavailable)`.
As soon as the backend gRPC service is running again, I am reciving the `unkown service api/proto.Service` error.

As requested, my `docker-compose.yaml` file:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  postgres:
    container_name: postgres
    hostname: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./management/postgres/postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    build: ./management/postgres/
    ports: 
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=$DB_USER
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$DB_PWD
      - POSTGRES_DB=$DB_NAME

  backend:
    container_name: backend
    ports: 
      - "50051:50051"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    build: ./service
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$DB_PWD

  envoy:
    build: ./management/proxies
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

My `envoy.yaml` proxy:

```yaml
admin:
  access_log_path: /tmp/admin_access.log
  address:
    socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 9901 }

static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: listener_0
    address:
      socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 8000 }
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          codec_type: auto
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local_service
              domains: ["*"]
              routes:
              - match: { prefix: "/" }
                route:
                  cluster: grpc_server 
                  timeout: 0s
                  max_stream_duration:
                    grpc_timeout_header_max: 0s
              cors:
                allow_origin_string_match:
                - prefix: "*"
                allow_methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
                allow_headers: keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout
                max_age: "1728000"
                expose_headers: custom-header-1,grpc-status,grpc-message
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.grpc_web
          - name: envoy.filters.http.cors
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
  clusters:
  - name: grpc_server
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: logical_dns
    http2_protocol_options: {}
    lb_policy: round_robin
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: cluster_0
      endpoints:
        - lb_endpoints:
            - endpoint:
                address:
                  socket_address:
                    address: backend
                    port_value: 50051
```

Comment: Can you include a minimal working example (for example a `docker-compose` file, with the exact implementation of your gRPC service) ?

Comment: Hi @norbjd, I added a `docker-compose` file as an edit. Do you have any ideas? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Does it work without the nginx ? Does your grpc-web client can get a succesful response when contacting <your-envoy>:8000 ?

Comment: Yes, it works without nginx.

Comment: Sorry for asking you directly @norbjd, but do you have any ideas? I still have not figured out anything further and I am stuck on this for a while now :)

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your issue with a containerized nginx but I failed to reproduce your issue, I'm having a 426 Upgrade Required :( Maybe if you try to containerize your nginx and make it work it will be more easy for others to reproduce your issue and then debug.

Comment: I have finished reproducing your architecture, but I did not encountered issues. Check this repo here : https://github.com/norbjd/grpc-web-nginx-envoy. The only difference I see is that my NGINX have `location /api/` instead of `location/api` (missing trailing slash). I hope this repo can help finding your issue.

Comment: Wow awesome, thank you so much norbjd! I will take a look at it and see if I can figure my error out :)